# Accessing the ADDed parent model instance in the clean() method of an inline model instance on the same Django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

When a Django model `A` has a relation to another model `B`, we can design the the admin page for `A` instance addition in a way that it also presents a formset to add inline instances of `B` (that will be associated to the created `A` instance).

The problem we are facing is that, when `B` clean() method is invoked, the instance of `A` is not yet saved in the DB, and we cannot access it directly through `B`'s field (it would raise an `A.DoesNotExist` exception).

Is there nonetheless a way to access the data that were filled-in for the `A` fields from `B` clean method ?

In particular, we noted that the `A` instance is created (yet not saved to DB) before `B` clean() method is invoked, as the admin is calling `save(commit=False)`. This `A` instance is forwarded to the formset of `B` as its `instance` field, but it does not seem to be forwarded from the formset down to its forms.